# How to set type for known error in redux-toolkit asyncThunk in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

## This is my async thunk

I'm making a login async thunk using axios api
signUpUser is a axios funciton that make post request to server

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { logInUser, signUpUser } from '../../Api'
import { ILoginForm, ISignupForm, IUser } from '../../Types'

interface IResponse {
    status: number,
    message: string,
    user: {
        token: string,
        profile: IUser
    }
}
interface IError {
    status: number ,
    message: string
}

export const signup = createAsyncThunk('/users/signup', async (data: ISignupForm) => {
    const response = await signUpUser(data)
    return response.data as IResponse
})

export const login = createAsyncThunk<IResponse, ILoginForm, { rejectValue: IError }>('/users/login', async (data: ILoginForm, thunkApi) => {
    try {
        const response = await logInUser(data)
        return response.data as IResponse
    } catch (error) {
          return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error.data as IError);
    }
   
})
```

## This is my auth slice

this is auth slice it holds loading , user and error so i want this error to be what server is returned .
server return this formate when it's error {status:number,message:string}

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { IUser } from '../../Types';
import { login, signup } from '../actions/auth';


interface Istate {
    loading: boolean;
    user: null | {
        token: null | string;
        profile: IUser | null
    }
    error: string | null;
}


const storedUser = localStorage.getItem('user');

const initialState: Istate = {
    loading: false,
    user: storedUser?JSON.parse(storedUser):null,
    error: null
}

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        logout: (state) => {
            state.user = null;
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
        }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        // ************************* Signup ************************
        builder.addCase(signup.pending, (state) => {
            state.error = null;
            state.loading = true
        })
        builder.addCase(signup.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false
            state.user = action.payload.user
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(action.payload.user))
        })
        builder.addCase(signup.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false,
                state.error = action.error.message || 'unknown error'
        })
        // **************** Login **************************************
        builder.addCase(login.pending,(state)=>{
            state.loading=true;
            state.error=null;
        })
        builder.addCase(login.fulfilled,(state,action)=>{
            state.loading=false;
            state.user=action.payload.user
            localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(action.payload.user))
        })
        builder.addCase(login.rejected,(state,action)=>{
            state.loading=false;
            state.error=action.payload?.message|| 'unknown error'
        })
    }
})

export const { logout } = authSlice.actions

export default authSlice.reducer
```

I want when request is rejected then original error returend from server should be set as error in auth slice

but when i want to try error.data as IError interface

```
 return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error.data as IError);
```

but typescript shows warning on error.data    'error' is of type 'unknown'.

how to solve that